# pine SCRIPT strategy.entry limit params NOT SET

Tags: pine-script

when pine script 'strategy.entry' limit params not set, what price of the order to entry order? next open price?
like this:  strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, no limit specifications create a market order to be executed at next available price. In the sense of confirmed close signals, this is the open of the bar following. Note that you will still need to specify for the "when" argument of the call, or place the call in the local scope of an if statement. eg:

```
if longCondition
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
```

or

```
strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, when= longCondition)
```

Cheers and best of luck

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much for your answer